# Field Value Hidden Unless Data Record's Cell Selected

Tags: filemaker

When I view a particular FileMaker Pro layout, the calculated field Invoice Check Grouping shows up as blank when viewed in either list or grid mode. However, while in grid mode, if I click on a particular Invoice Check Grouping cell, the expected value appears.

[image]

In the above image, note how only the currently selected Invoice Check Grouping cell's value shows. I would expect all cells in that column to correctly show their values all the time.

How would I get this column's value appearing all the time? (Note: Invoice Check Grouping is a computed/calculated field.)

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong with either the formula itself or, perhaps, the field's formatting. E.g. it could be that the calculation type is set to Number, and the field's Number formatting is set not to show the value when zero. If this is not the case, I'd check the field's conditional formatting rules and then the formula itself.

Comment: Under the "Specify Calculation" dialog, the calculation result type was set to number. Changing it to text (since the calculation outputted text) fixed the problem. Thank you much!